# BigInt in node 12 (v12.22.12)

Tags: node.js, bigint

I'd like to use BigInt with node 12.22.12. It works fine in the REPL but in my script I need to "require" it. I tried things like `const BigInt = require('BigInt')` or `require('node:bigint')` and different mixes but it's not working...

Comment: `BigInt` has been in NodeJS since ~10.mumble. More context may be required to diagnose any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BigInt` is a core part of the JS language (built into the interpreter itself).  You don't `require()` it.  You can just use it as in:

```
let x = BigInt("9007199254740991");
let y = 9007199254740991n;

console.log(x, y);
```

Comment: Right ! Thanks ! ESLint was just fooling me ('BigInt' is not defined.)

Comment: @raphaelSeguin - It sounds like you need a new ESLint that knows about BigInt being part of the language.